# python - assignment in text document

Tags: python, file, search, variable-assignment

i have a file and it is made up with different values. and i need to define them and then search through them.

in the file i have - number, number 2, job type, first name, last name.

how would i make it so it will search the hole file for that name or number then bring up the other vaules in that line?

all i have at the moment is opening the file :(, i am stumped.

```
import csv

fname = input(open("Please enter the name of the file you wish to open: ")
```

im usign python 3.0

Comment: text doc or csv file???

Comment: You should try something to be stumped. If you are still stuck, read more documentation or examples.

Answer (score 3):

just start with the [documentation's example](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader)!

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        print ', '.join(row)
```

result:

```
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

in your case:

```
import csv

value1 = "Spam"

fname = input(open("Please enter the name of the file you wish to open: ")

with open(fname, 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        if value1 in row: # if the string of value1 is exactly one of the cells of the row
            print " ".join(row) # printout the full row
```

if you do your homework well, and read thoroughly the mighty documentation, you'll find out there are better ways to actually work with csv than what I'm suggesting (though starting with what I'm giving, you can make something working fine).

But here I'm not to write code for you, all I want is to give you a hint so you can get started coding!

Comment: I'm not saying it's an homework, I'm just telling you to *do* your homework by reading the documentation, where all the answers are! If the with syntax is causing an error, you should check your python version, chances are you're not using a recent version of python. `python --version` should be 2.7 or 3.something